# SQLAlchemy property shadowing

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, gino

I have a table in my Postgresql database that has a column with a given name (for instance `order_id`) and also I have a JSON column that contains the property `order_id`. Now this is something I cannot have control of at this moment. But what I need to do is put this into a model class. I use SQLAlchemy and Gino on top. So what I have is something like this

```
class Order(db.orm.Model):
    """Blueprint for the orders"""

    __tablename__ = "orders"
    id = db.orm.Column(db.orm.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    order_id = db.orm.Column(db.orm.Text(), index=True, nullable=False)
    properties = db.orm.Column(JSON)
    order_id = db.orm.StringProperty(prop_name="properties")
```

What happens here is that I have two properties with the same name. I tried using `synonym` for one of them, but that didn't work as I hoped it would.

```
class Order(db.orm.Model):
    """Blueprint for the orders"""

    __tablename__ = "orders"
    id = db.orm.Column(db.orm.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    properties = db.orm.Column(JSON)
    order_id = db.orm.StringProperty(prop_name="properties")
    order_id_alias = synonym('order_id')
    order_id = db.orm.Column(db.orm.Text(), index=True, nullable=False)
```

So is there a way I can define an alias for this JSON property. Something along these lines

```
    order_id_alias = db.orm.StringProperty(prop_name="properties->>type")
    # OR LIKE THIS
    order_id_alias = db.orm.StringProperty(prop_name="properties.type")
```

Also what would work in my case is to just ignore the existence of `properties.order_id` by removing

```
order_id = db.orm.StringProperty(prop_name="properties")
```

but with the current setup, I get an error

```
`order_id` is found in `properties` of instance <Order object at 0x11ff18be1>, but column `order_id` is not an instance of the `JSONProperty` type.
```